# Select existing circle node in d3 and append childs

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I have a concept map where a child node may have it's child at run time. What I am trying to achieve is to expand the child node on click so that I can show it's children nodes.

```
    var childNode = d3.select("#o0");

    var onode = childNode.append('g')
        .data(data.outer)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "outer_node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(-86)translate(340)"; });

    onode.append("circle")
        .attr('id', function (d) { return d.id })
        .attr("r", 4.5);
```

I am getting error on below line:

> var onode = childNode.append('g')

... saying undefined

Comment: Can you put a plunkr or fiddle? We have little idea on what is going on. Are you trying to append the child node as an element? Have you checked the patterns of what you are trying to accomplish? There are lots of good examples out there: http://jsfiddle.net/ajing/Q2c2X/7/

Comment: fiddle is restricted in my company

Answer (score 0):

It should have been as shown below.

```
 var onode = childNode.selectAll(".outer_node")
        .data(data.outer)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "outer_node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(-86)translate(340)"; });
```

You need to give a selection for data binding.

Comment: Thanks Cyril. I will give a try